# how to acess a key by its value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering, is there a way i can get a key by knowing its value? For example a code so you can just add the part with finding a key by its value.

```
ww = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
counts = dict()
words = ww.split()
val = []
for word in words:
    if word in counts:
        counts[word] += 1
    else:
        counts[word] = 1


for keys, values in counts.items():
    val.append(int(values))
```

here is the code the adds the word and how many times can we meet it in the code.

Comment: what is exactly your question?

Comment: Not directly. You need to loop through the key/value pairs and find the key(s) with a given value.

Comment: so how do i do that?

Comment: @MarkMeyer is the person asking if they can access a Key knowing its value? What if we have 2 equal values?

Comment: @JustStarted what do you mean how? You are already doing that in the code you are showing.

Comment: @ombk that's why I said `key(s)`

Comment: I solved this one, thanks a lot for your help. This looks so trivial but dont know why i couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a function for this:

```
def get_key_by_value(dictionary, value):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if v == value:
            return k
    return None

test_dict = {"one": "two", "two": "three"}
print(get_key_by_value("two")) # "one"
```

**Note:** This function only returns the first value - and since this is an unordered `dict`, it might specify any key with the value given. To fix this, you could add all the results to a list:

```
def get_keys_by_value(dictionary, value):
    result = []
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if v == value:
            result.append(k)
    return result

test_dict = {"one": "two", "two": "three"}
print(get_keys_by_value("two")) # ["one"]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what i was looking for